# Why are there only a finite number of people?

Tags: number, theology, reward-punishment

If the purpose that we ascribe as the reason for creation (as stated in the Ramchal's Derech Hashem, Klach Pischei Chochma and other works) is for God to bestow his goodness unto creation (bearing in mind that this does not refer to the actual will of God, but rather an approximation based on our limited understanding) why are there so few human beings around for him to do this to?

Shouldn't an infinite God want to bestow as much good as possible and thus require as many people (or living things - if we assume they also experience that goodness) as possible?

Comment: Wouldn't you need an infinite number of people to satisfy that goal?

Comment: @MonicaCellio or, you would need to explain the importance of having a finite number of people instead ;)

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the question (and the premises on which it depends).

Comment: @MonicaCellio the premise is that God wants to give good (chok ha'tov l'heitiv) if that is his desire why limit the recipients, more recipients means dolling out more good which in turn means more fulfillment of his will. Please let me know if you feel I need to edit any of this into the question.

Comment: I'd have to a little research to back this up with sources, but my understanding is that, in reality, we literally cannot speak of God's motivations. In fact, the entire idea of a motivation or purpose cannot actually be applied to God. Thus, when we speak of the "purpose of Creation" we are, by definition, speaking of something on a level below God Himself - i.e. something that is itself part of creation and therefore limited.

Comment: @LazerA i agree 100% we cannot speak about God himself, but we can ascribe or assign meaning to what he has done based on our limited understanding in an attempt to relate to him better. this is what the Ramchal (among others) has done in ascribing a reason to creation. My question is based on that assumption you would expect there to either A) be an infinite number of created beings or B) have a darn good reason why the number is finite

Comment: Your question appears to based on the premise that an infinite God that wishes to bestow goodness should require an infinite number of recipients. However, that assumes that the "motivation" (wants to bestow goodness) can actually be applied to God. If the motivation is actually only a rough human approximation of something which, in reality, is entirely beyond the ken of any created being, then it is difficult to say that there is a real question here (or, if there is, if there is any humanly possible way to answer it).

Comment: @LazerA Are you saying that we cannot use the phrase "ratzon haboreh"? Or that the Ramchal is incorrect in his assertion of a reason for creation?

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me. Olam haba, which is the primary period in which God will bestow His goodness upon His creations is eternal (i.e. infinite). If the recipients exist for all infinity, isn't that effectively the same as an infinite number of recipients? Especially as God exists outside of time, which means that as long as there is at least one recipient in Olam Haba, then, from God's "perspective", He can bestow His infinite goodness on an infinitely large recipient.

Comment: No, but, as with all such concepts (especially in Kabbalistic sources), we have to recognize that we are dealing with human approximations of concepts that are often beyond human ken, and that almost nothing we say is actually dealing with God Himself. That is Basic Kaballah 101.

Comment: @LazerA agreed, is that not clear in the question?

Comment: @LazerA I'm not sure if this is a response, but see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number).

Comment: Who said there are only a finite number of people? God can see the future just as well as the present.

Comment: perhaps God created infinite other worlds with human beings and does not tell us so as to make us feel important.

Comment: To the extent that we can ascribe / suggest / understand Hashem's motivations, I would suggest that if there were indeed an infinite number of recipients, then a single individual might perceive the good he has received as infinitesimally small, and therefore perhaps less worthy of his own consideration and appreciation. No sources, though.